# Web Scraping a page with multiple tables

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web scrape the second table from this website:
https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats
However, I have only ever managed to extract the information from the first table when trying to access the information by finding the table tag. Would anyone be able to explain to me why I cannot access the second table or show me how to do it.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
pl_table = soup.find_all("table")  
player_table = tables[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table is inside HTML comments `<!-- ... -->`.

To get the table from comments, you can use this example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

table = BeautifulSoup(soup.select_one('#all_stats_standard').find_next(text=lambda x: isinstance(x, Comment)), 'html.parser')

#print some information from the table to screen:
for tr in table.select('tr:has(td)'):
    tds = [td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td')]
    print('{:<30}{:<20}{:<10}'.format(tds[0], tds[3], tds[5]))
```

Prints:

```
Patrick van Aanholt           Crystal Palace      1990      
Max Aarons                    Norwich City        2000      
Tammy Abraham                 Chelsea             1997      
Che Adams                     Southampton         1996      
Adrián                        Liverpool           1987      
Sergio Agüero                 Manchester City     1988      
Albian Ajeti                  West Ham            1997      
Nathan Aké                    Bournemouth         1995      
Marc Albrighton               Leicester City      1989      
Toby Alderweireld             Tottenham           1989      

...and so on.
```

Comment: This website requires javascript for the 2nd to the 11th table. If you load the page, it takes a bit longer for the other tables to appear, that is because javascript is being used to get it.

Comment: @AaronS The data you see in the page is already there, but inside `<!-- ... -->` comments. You can get this information without JavaScript.

Comment: My mistake. I can't seem to find it in the html inspecting it. I see the comment but it doesn't have 500 odd rows of information but your code checks out. I've deleted my comment to help not confuse the OP.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! As you can tell I'm very new to Python and web scraping so there is still a lot for me to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should do it

```
tables = soup.find_all("table")  # returns a list of tables
second_table = tables[1]
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added my code into my initial question. When I attempted this, it told me that 1 was out of the index, so when I web scraped the page, it was only picking up the first table. Although when I look at the source code, the second table does have distinct table tags to the first table.

Comment: This website requires javascript for the 2nd to the 11th table. If you load the page, it takes a bit longer for the other tables to appear, that is because javascript is being used to get it.

Comment: nice catch @AaronS!  I had not noticed that

Comment: Hi Chris! So the answer below by Andrej, shows that it can be achieved by pure HTML. Apparently the data is within the comment section. Silly me! I'd spend time writing about dynamic content and scraping to find that out ha! Check out his answer.