# Can't identify a table when scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping

Beginner question.. I'm attempting to scrape data from a table but I can't seem to recognize it, I've tried using the class and the id to identify it but my result is 0. The code and output are below.

```
# Import necessary packages
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
# Site URL
url="https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats"

# Make a GET request to fetch the raw HTML content
html_content = requests.get(url).text

# Parse HTML code for the entire site
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
#print(soup.prettify()) # print the parsed data of html

gdp = soup.find_all("table", attrs={"id": "stats_standard"})
print("Number of tables on site: ",len(gdp))
```

```
Output - 'Number of tables on site:  0'
```

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62969630/11380795) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use selenium for such scraping, its performance is very reliable.

This code will work for you:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.add_argument('--headless')
url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/stats/Premier-League-Stats'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
driver.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
gdp = bs.find_all('table', {'id': 'stats_standard'})
driver.quit()
print("Number of tables on site: ",len(gdp))
```

**Output**

```
Number of tables on site:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you find the table(s) without using `attrs={"id": "stats_standard"}`?

I have checked and indeed I cannot find any table whose ID is `stats_standard` (but there is one with ID `stats_standard_sh`, for example). So I guess you might be using the wrong ID.